# Add "are you sure? (y/n)" prompt before executing python script

Tags: python, command-line

Say I have python script, call it "script.py".

Normally, in the command line, file executes when user types "python script.py".

What I want is to add an "are you sure? (y/n)" prompt after user types "python script.py". And only after typing y [enter] should the script execute.

Comment: Have you tried an `if` statement?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a basic tutorial service.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could put something like this at the start of your script

```
if input("are you sure? (y/n)") != "y":
    exit()
```

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3.0.